# When I launch my python script the expected screen doesn't appear

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a life system so where you get an answer wrong it takes away a life. And if you have zero lives the game ends.

Also, I want to make it so if you type a certain thing it starts the quiz, if you type anything else you lose all your lives, and if you also type this certain thing it ends the quiz immediately.

I tried doing this but when i pressed run it runs, but doesnt do anything; the screen turns blank.

Here's my code:

```
import time
import random
livesRemaining = 3
def main():
    global livesRemaining
    while True:
        if livesRemaining == 0:
            break    
    time.sleep(.1)
    q= input("welcome to the test about the ancient gods. NO SEARCHING ANYTHING UP!!!! to start the quiz type, Ok i wont search anything up. If you dont want to start the quiz type, i dont care i will search the answers up.")
    if q== "Ok i wont search anything up.":
            print("ok, good luck.")
    else: 
        print ("Goodbye, until we meet again")
        livesRemaining -= 3
    if q== "i dont care i will search the answers up.":
        print("Your a cheater, now you can't play this round!!!!")
        livesRemaining -= 3 
    time.sleep(2)
    q1= input("what was the greek god of sleep?")
    q1= q1.lower()
    if q1== "hypnos":
        print("congrats, you payed attention in social studies class from elemen-tary school.")
    else:
        print("HA, imagine not paying attention in social studies class.")

    time.sleep(2)
    q2= input("What was the name of the greek goddess of the night?")
    q2= q2.lower()
    if q2== "nyx":
        print("congrats, you payed attention in social studies class from element-ary school.")
    else:
        print("HA, imagine not paying attention in social studies class.")
```

Comment: you have to add `main()` at the end to execute function.

Comment: ok thank you, i appreacite it

Comment: ummm, when i do that, the python mini console freezes and i cant do anything.

Comment: you have endless loop `while True: if livesRemaining == 0: break` because inside this loop you never change `livesRemaining` so it never exit. You have to run rest of your code inside `while True`. So you have to change `indentations`

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: nope doesnt work

Comment: if it doesn't work then you may have different problem (and I don't know what it is) or you have different code. And maybe you should try to use `print()` to see which part of code is executed.

Comment: maybe its because im using python mini instead of python?

Comment: what do you means `mini python`? Can you add link to this version?

Comment: ok, python mini is what my middle school coding class uses. Normal python will be fully finished in janurary - feburary of 2024

Comment: this is the share link to my python mini project: https://mams.oyoclass.com/app/pythonmini/file/6571f9bd9d375a6f42be7d14/snapshot/20231213-201540-0a49a536d1a8cbb3d639780b2adac12c

Comment: when I run code from your link (in Firefox) then I see popup windows with questions - see image https://imgur.com/a/yRVdD8V . Maybe you have some `adblock` which blocks  these popups ? Or maybe you checked `Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs` and now it doesn't show popups. And this may need to check settings in web browser to remove this setting.

Comment: i can try sending you a link to the website homepage instead of the website on my python mini project. would that help?

Comment: you may add link. Maybe it has problem to run something.

Comment: ok, i dont know if it will let you on because your not a mentor for the website. Also im sorry to waste your time, i only just started coding on the first day of middle school for me. im in seventh grade. It wont let me send a link to the website, it only lets me send a link on my account. I hope that only you get this link because i have a bunch of stuff on there, i only trust you : https://mams.oyoclass.com/mine

Comment: I can't login on your account (I'm not mentor for this website). You will have to test it on your own. You can try different browser, without extensions, without AdBlocks, etc.

Comment: ok let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You have endless loop

```
while True: 
   if livesRemaining == 0: 
      break
```

You don't have any other code inside this loop so it never changes `livesRemaining`,
and it can't exit this loop. So program runs forever. And console freezes.

You have to run rest of your code inside `while True`.
So you have to change `indentations`

```
import time
import random

def main():
    livesRemaining = 3

    while True:
        if livesRemaining <= 0:  # sometimes result may be smaller than 0
            break    

        time.sleep(.1)
        q = input("welcome to the test about the ancient gods. NO SEARCHING ANYTHING UP!!!! to start the quiz type, Ok i wont search anything up. If you dont want to start the quiz type, i dont care i will search the answers up.")
        if q == "Ok i wont search anything up.":
            print("ok, good luck.")
        else: 
            print("Goodbye, until we meet again")
            livesRemaining -= 3
        if q == "i dont care i will search the answers up.":
            print("Your a cheater, now you can't play this round!!!!")
            livesRemaining -= 3 

        time.sleep(2)
        q = input("what was the greek god of sleep?")
        q = q.lower()
        if q == "hypnos":
            print("congrats, you payed attention in social studies class from elemen-tary school.")
        else:
            print("HA, imagine not paying attention in social studies class.")
        
        time.sleep(2)
        q = input("What was the name of the greek goddess of the night?")
        q = q.lower()
        if q == "nyx":
            print("congrats, you payed attention in social studies class from element-ary school.")
        else:
            print("HA, imagine not paying attention in social studies class.")

# --- start ---
main()
```